# I got "System Exit 2" when run on Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

When i run Addernet by code proivde by it own paper
source code : https://github.com/huawei-noah/AdderNet
, i faced "System Exit 2" when use args, here is piece of code where i face that error

```
import os
from resnet20 import resnet20
import torch
from torch.autograd import Variable
from torchvision.datasets import CIFAR10
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader 
import argparse
import math

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='train-addernet')

# Basic model parameters.
parser.add_argument('--data', type=str, default='/cache/data/')
parser.add_argument('--output_dir', type=str, default='/cache/models/')
args = parser.parse_args()

os.makedirs(args.output_dir, exist_ok=True)
```

thank a lots